# I have a promblem child.html -> parent.html i want get value but cross-domain issue

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

child.html -> parent.html 
 i want get value  child value to parent
but cross-domial issue happened
please help me...

I test in localhtml

***Parent.html***

```
    var openWin;

    function openChild()
    {
        // window.name = "Parent Name"; 
        window.name = "parentForm";
        // window.open("open할 window", "ChildValue", "팝업창 옵션");
        openWin = window.open("Child.html",
                "childForm", "width=570, height=350, resizable = no, scrollbars = no");    
    }
```

```
<b><font size="5" color="gray">Parent</font></b>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="openChild" onclick="openChild()"><br>
전달할 값 : <input type="text" id="pInput">
```

***Child.html***

```
    function setParentText(){
         opener.document.getElementById("pInput").value = document.getElementById("cInput").value
    }
```

```
<font size="5" color="gray">childWindow</font></b>
<input type="text" id="cInput"> <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="setParentText()">

<input type="button" value="closeWindow" onclick="window.close()">
```

[parent view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yJ5z.jpg)

[child view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbyDY.jpg)

[err code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xKiz.jpg)

Comment: Why do you need to open a new window

Comment: What do you mean by "cross-domain issue" happened?

Comment: are they same domain? if not, then yes, cross domain issue will happened